# Utility for communicating with a database over an ODBC driver in Linux shell

Tags: c, database, linux, bash, driver

**Here's my situation:**

- I have a driver for Linux that should allow communication with SQL Server
- I need to be able to issue commands to the database from the command line (bash)

**My Question**

Is there some program/utility I can use on Linux that can send commands to a database using any ODBC driver (including ones I specify)?

---

**Note:**  I'm basically looking for a Linux version of the SQLCMD utility that ships with SQL Server.  I'd be happy with any program that could use just the basic database functions supported by all ODBC drivers though.

Comment: The utility is called isql , and is part of unixODBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Dbvisualizer : http://www.dbvis.com/download/

1. Free version that can be downloaded and you can do basic SQL commands
2. Available on Linux
3. Has a command line interface (maybe not all versions)
4. Adding your own driver : From your question I understand that you have your own custom ODBC driver that you want to use instead of Microsoft sqljdbc4.jar (Correct me if I am wrong). As shown in link below, you can actually point to any driver file. http://www.dbvis.com/doc/8.0/doc/ug/getConnected/getConnected.html
   DBvisualizer does some basic validation(driver classes etc.) before it imports that driver file you pointed it to

What I still do not understand is how you can force SQL Server to believe that it is using sqljdbc.jar when it is using your custom driver?

Comment: I'll be honest, this isn't my strong point so I'm still figuring this out.  The version of Linux we're stuck using doesn't support the generic SQL Server driver though, so we've had to get one from a third party vendor that ported it.  Trying to figure out a way to use the third party one with an existing command line sql utility.  I'll look at Dbvisualizer tonight. :) Thanks.

Comment: Yw!!... Can you please let me know what version of Linux and what distro you are using?...Apparently, at a glance, it looks like MSFT supports Linux 5 and Linux 6 for RedHat. I haven't tried this myself. However, here's a link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160

Answer (score 2):

[FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org) provides connectivity from Linux to MS SQL Server. 
It comes with a set of command-line tools and also an ODBC driver that can be used to established client program connectivity via [unixodbc](http://www.unixodbc.org).
Something along the lines of client->unixODBC->freeTDS->SQL Server